# How to run a JSF 2.0 application on JavaEE5?

Tags: java, jsf-2, weblogic-10.x

For one reason or another, we need to run our JSF2 application on a JavaEE5 server (weblogic10).

Before trying to compile my application with Java5 instead of Java6, does anyone know if this will actually be possible?

Comment: You know that Java (SE) 5 and Java EE 5 don't depend on each other, don't you? You should be able to run any Java EE 5 appliction server in a Java 6 VM without problems (except maybe some libraries that might differ, which you could replace then).

Comment: AFAIK JSF 2 doesn't depend on Java EE 6, so that shouldn't be a problem as well. You simply replace the JSF implementation of your application server and should be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF 2.0 is compatible with Servlet 2.5 (Java EE 5) containers. See also the [Mojarra 2.0 release notes](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.0/releasenotes.html):

> ### Webtier Specification Requirements
>
> This release of JSF requires:
>
> - [Java Servlet 2.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html)
> - [JavaServer<sup>TM</sup> Pages 2.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html)
> - [JavaServer<sup>TM</sup> Pages Standard Tag Library 1.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

Only JSF 2.1 requires Servlet 3.0 (Java EE 6) containers. See also the [Mojarra 2.1 release notes](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.0/releasenotes.html).

Comment: You're welcome. The only "JSF 2.0 feature" which you'll miss is the ability to invoke non-getter methods and methods with arguments in EL such as `action="#{bean.edit(item)}"`. This was introduced in EL 2.2 which comes along with Java EE 6. You can however consider to install JBoss EL to add the same feature to EL 2.1 (part of Java EE 5). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877494/upgrade-jboss-5-1-from-el-2-1-to-el-2-2 (works also on non-JBoss containers).

Comment: Unfortunately the JBossEL breaks compatibility with Tomcat6, as that runs JSP2.1 which appears to be incompatible with JBossEL. I guess replacing the jars in the server is the only solution to get one build work on so many different servers. There goes java's build once, run everywhere :D

Comment: It works for me on Tomcat 6. Perhaps the `/WEB-INF/lib` was littered with EL 2.2 specific classes such as `el-api.jar`, `el-impl.jar` from Glassfish 3.