# el-api 2.2 on jboss 5.1

Tags: java, jsf, el, jboss5.x

I would like to use el-api 2.2 on jboss 5.1. I can't use el-jboss because it conflict with JSF validation on BigDecimal types. 
I've integrated el-api 2.2 in my project and on tomcat it work smooth. When I try to deploy on Jboss, I feel that he is loading el-api 1.0 from his common lib dir instead my jar because I obtain this stack trace:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ELResolver.invoke(Ljavax/el/ELContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:1593)[...]
```

my web.xml is configured right (it's my third day on google...)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I know that overriding of the lib bundled with Jboss will work, but I can't use this technique for the production server

Comment: Have you tried replacing the jar in the lib folder of your JBoss server?

Comment: Replacing the jar will work but I can't do that on the production server. That's why I'm searching for another solution.

Comment: if I use el-jboss 2.0.0.GA I obtain this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch when I use <f:converter converterId="importoConverter" />
       <f:attribute name="pattern" value="#,###,##0.000" />

Comment: I asked the same question a while ago... see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877494/upgrade-jboss-5-1-from-el-2-1-to-el-2-2

Comment: I've seen your question before asking my. I can't use the solution proposed, because there is an incompatibility between my BigDecimal converter and el-jboss. To much reflection has the effect that I'm not able to make them work together